# send multiple image to server : One image sending thrice to server issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask

- I have to send three different images in server side.Right now one
  image is uploading thrice.But I have chosen three different image.
- Because I had given count=0.then it takes first image and send the
  first image thrice to the server.
- If I give the count=1 then it takes the second image thrice to send
  to the server at a time.
- I don't know how to give a count for 0,1 and 2 at a time to send the
  three images.So that I can send the three images at a time to send it to the server.

**Logcat:**

```
02-11 04:32:20.565: E/params[0](16395): 0
02-11 04:32:20.582: E/ParamsArray(16395): [0, pk0.jpg]
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button upload, pick;
    MultipartEntity entity;
    GridView gv;
    int count = 0;
    public ArrayList<String> map = new ArrayList<String>();
    Bundle b;
    TextView noImage;


   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ImageUploadTask().execute(count + "", "pk" + count + ".jpg");

                /*Log.e("url", url);
                new UserProfileUpdateAsynTask().execute(url);*/
            }
        });
}

class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        ProgressDialog dialog;
        String url = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpEntity resEntity;  

            int i = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            Log.e("params[0]",""+i);

            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(map.get(i));
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            entity = new MultipartEntity();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            try {

                Log.e("ParamsArray",""+Arrays.toString(params));



            entity.addPart("filename[0]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
            entity.addPart("filename[1]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
            entity.addPart("filename[2]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));


                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                resEntity = response.getEntity();
                String entityContentAsString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                return entityContentAsString;

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result != null) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("Update_profile", result);

            }
        }

    }



}
```

Anyone can help me with this.Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> entity.addPart("filename[0]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
> entity.addPart("filename[1]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
> entity.addPart("filename[2]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
> ```

*You are sending same file three times that's the problem.*

---

Better to put images path in **[SharedPrefrence](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)**.

```
    byte[] data1 = null,data2= null,data3= null;

    if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).contains("endum_image_0"))
    {       up_image1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getString("endum_image_0", "");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(up_image1, options1);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos1);
            data1 = bos1.toByteArray();
    }
    if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).contains("endum_image_1"))
    {       up_image2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getString("endum_image_1", "");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(up_image2, options1);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos2);
            data2 = bos2.toByteArray();
    }

    if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).contains("endum_image_2"))
    {       up_image3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getString("endum_image_2", "");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(up_image3, options1);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos3);
            data3 = bos3.toByteArray();
    }
```

if byte array have data then only send it to server

```
    if(data1!=null){
    entity.addPart("files[]", new ByteArrayBody(data1,"image/jpeg", "u1.jpg"));
    }
    if(data2!=null){
    entity.addPart("files[]", new ByteArrayBody(data2,"image/jpeg", "u2.jpg"));
    }

    if(data3!=null){
    entity.addPart("files[]", new ByteArrayBody(data3,"image/jpeg", "u3.jpg"));
    }
```

---

**Sending Data on server:**

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }

    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    {
        return s.toString();
    }else
    {
        return "{\"status\":\"false\",\"message\":\"Some error occurred\"}";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the same file that's why you are receiving same image thrice. Look at your code

```
 entity.addPart("filename[0]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
            entity.addPart("filename[1]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
            entity.addPart("filename[2]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
```

In the above code `params[1]` refers to the same file `pk0.jpg`. If you want to send different images then you should do something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
entity.addPart("filename[" + i + "]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", "pk" + i + ".jpg"));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: now it is not sending any image to server.initially   int count = 0; thats why it is not executing inside the for loop and then I set i<3 in loop.it is taking three image thrice.

Comment: Please show the server code which you are using for saving purpose. it looks like that server is replicating.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider SOLID Principal Well.. I would say.. Instead of passing Strings in Parameter .. Why don't you pass custom Models Array.. This way in future you can use uploader for Different Datatype .. And This gives you flexibility.

For Example

```
public class Image {
public Bitmap bitmap;
public String dataType;
public String name;
}
```

And Than You can create your `AsynTask` as below.

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Image, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        String url = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Image... params) {
            HttpEntity resEntity;  
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            entity = new MultipartEntity();


          try {

            for(int i;i<params.length;i++) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                params[i].bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                entity.addPart("filename["+i+"]", new ByteArrayBody(data,params[i].dataType, params[i].name));
            }




                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                resEntity = response.getEntity();
                String entityContentAsString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                return entityContentAsString;

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result != null) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("Update_profile", result);

            }
        }

    }
```